# getting connection reset error message in custom order listing module in magento?

Tags: magento

I have made one custom module in Magento 1.4.1.1 for order listing. This module is the same as the Magento order listing module.
I am getting the collection in _prepareCollection -> grid.php block file.
I am using this code for getting the order listing same as admin order listing :

```
Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection');
```

When I check the collection, there are only 10 records in it, and also I am getting reset connection error message.

Check this function:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{ 
     $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection');           
     $this->setCollection($collection);
     parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Same code is working perfect in magento 1.5.0.1 but not working in magento 1.4.1.1

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more your request?

Comment: i have used the same order grid as sales->order grid used in magento admin, i have used same code in my custom module but i am facing the "reset connection.." error and not getting the order listing.

Comment: "I have done this.  I am using this.  Please help?" -- You need to update your question with *way* more information.

Comment: your connection is probably reset cause you are calling for too much data at the time

Comment: @ Anton S : no, I am just calling it once.

Comment: How many seconds do you need to wait before getting the "reset connection error"? Could it be due to an operation taking more than expected?

Comment: I think that more code of your module could help. Can you post it?

Comment: same code is working perfect in magento 1.5.0.1

Answer (score 2):

In Magento's admin go to *System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings* and make sure exception logging is turned on, pay attention to where the exception log is. In the `.htaccess` file add these lines:

```
php_flag display_errors on
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE true
```

Now you will be able to see all sorts of error messages when something goes wrong and that can lead you to the real cause.

Comment: Still have an error :(. there isn't any system.log file and php error messages, i have checked it properly.

Comment: when i have checked the collection manually by echo-die statement then it has a data, dont know why i have this error :(